# CGAL how to install, how to compile on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: installation, compilation, dependencies, cgal

I am trying to use CGAL on Linux. I am a good coder, yet I am very bad at installation and compilation parts. I am not sure whether I have installed CGAL correctly. I've followed the steps in the following link: https://kezunlin.me/post/39ab7ed9/   to install. Now under my /usr/local/include directory I can see CGAL folder. But when i try to compile the examples, I fail.

For instance when I try to compile the example Triangulation_2 mentioned in the CGAL documentation page, first I go to its folder, I give the command `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and then I give `make` , it prints out the following errors like:

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Qt/qglviewer_impl.h:808:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::qglviewer::Camera::setScreenWidthAndHeight(int, int, int)’
  808 |   camera->setScreenWidthAndHeight(width(), height(), devicePixelRatio());
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.dir/build.make:112: CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.dir/CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/CGAL_Qt5_moc_and_resources.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Error text is very long actually.
I do not understand anything about these errors. Does it mean it can not reach some CGAL dependency or something else? What should I do?

As an other example, I tried to compile the tutorial example given in the following link: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html

I created the CMakeLists.txt given in the first link. This time, `make`  command gives the followings:

```
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h:203:3: error: static assertion failed: Error: no SVD traits
  203 |   CGAL_static_assertion_msg(!(boost::is_same<SvdTraits,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/CGAL/jet_smooth_point_set.h:203:3: note: ‘!(bool)boost::integral_constant<bool, true>::value’ evaluates to false


/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:9: error: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set<CGAL::Sequential_tag, CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> > >(CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >&, unsigned int, const CGAL::Named_function_parameters<bool, CGAL::internal_np::all_default_t>&)::<lambda(const reference&)>; _Constraints = void; _Res = bool; _ArgTypes = {boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >::Index&, boost::tuples::cons<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>&, boost::tuples::null_type> >}]’, declared using local type ‘CGAL::jet_smooth_point_set<CGAL::Sequential_tag, CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> > >(CGAL::Point_set_3<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Vector_3<CGAL::Epick> >&, unsigned int, const CGAL::Named_function_parameters<bool, CGAL::internal_np::all_default_t>&)::<lambda(const reference&)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
  435 |         function(_Functor&& __f)
      |         ^~~~~~~~
```

Again the error text is very long, I just crop here the some keyword parts.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you have Eigen installed and to "link" with Eigen in your cmake list?

Comment: Something like:
`
find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0 QUIET) #(requires 3.1.0 or greater)
include(CGAL_Eigen3_support)
if(TARGET CGAL::Eigen3_support)
   target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE  CGAL::Eigen3_support)
endif()
`

Comment: I learned that my Eigen version is 3.4.0. I have added the lines that you said by using 3.4.0. It gave the following error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    CGAL_Eigen3_support

Comment: By the way, for the example Triangulation_2, I guess that there is some other error (maybe related with the configuration that I used during the cgal installation) since I am already using the built-in CMakeLists.txt file provided by the CGAL download. During the installation, from the cmake-gui I only added the additional "QT5_DIR     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5" name-value pair. Should I install/add any other dependency? For instance I see boost and Qt folders under CGAL folder, but I can not see some folder related with Eigen. Should I see it?

Comment: The command `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` is wrong, you have to add a directory in the end, at least the current one `.`. Also, please include the 'cmake' output into your question